# MVC3 Razor - Javascript statements with nested server ifs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why doesn't the razor template engine like:

```
@if (Model.ActionComplete) {
  <script type="text/javascript">

      @if (Model.Message.IsString()) {

      }

  </script>
}
```

It is complaining that the `Model` in `Model.Message` should be a constant and that the `</script>` tag is missing an @end statement.

I am trying to get to:

```
@if (Model.ActionComplete) {
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#user-form").slideUp();
      @if (Model.Message.IsString()) {
        @:showMessageBar("@(Model.Message)");
      }
    });
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Because of seperation of concerns. Why are you compiling your javascript based on server side information? JavaScript is used to enhance experience, server side information is injected into your HTML. The view converts a Model into HTML. JavaScript should be in a seperate external file anyway, away from your server.

Comment: Thats not what I've asked, stick to the answer, I've not asked for an argument about adding View logic to my View.

Comment: Do you have this nested in any other Razor/<script> syntax?  The same exact construct seems to work fine in the context of my test application.

Comment: Do you get this error when running the application or is VS complaining, but the code works fine otherwise?  Seems that VS 2010 can't really handle this construct as far as its internal error check is concerned, but the code works fine when ran (I get the same errors you mention in VS).

Comment: @BobTodd: Raynos was trying to help you, no need to get defensive. This, IMHO with 12 years of web development,  is one of the worst practices in web development and forbidden at our shop. To avoid this error-prone mix of languages, I would have the server generate a JSON object that your script can use. That way your data, and your script are separated.

Comment: @BobTodd Razor doesn't like this since the syntax is very loose and ambigious when mixed in with JavaScript. The syntax difference between C# and HTML is easy. Figuring out what part of your inline C# is C# instead of JavaScript is a nightmare. Once again, designing your application with standard accepted practices would make this problem dissapear.

Comment: so its ok to conditionally display a div with a message to the user, but not some jQuery that does exactly the same thing? ur talking of a limitation of razor not best practices.

Comment: Juan I may have to respectfully disagree to an extent. There are times (especially with jQuery ui and ajax integration) where including @Model.X in javascript just makes sense. Sure - a very limited bit - but its still very commonplace. Maybe you are only talking about the case of 'logic' embedded cross language? Also - razor syntax highlighting should easily take care of the issue of trying to figure out the difference in language - thats why the highlighting was developed in the first place : ) If I want a grid with links to javascript ui for /Controller/Action/Index/XX to show a

Comment: popup dialog, somewhere along the lines my javascript needs an ID of my current item to show.

Comment: Either support it or don't. I've been putting up with half-baked jobs from the gu and co for over a century and its starting to wear thin :D

Comment: @BobTodd @AdamTuliper JavaScript is an external _client-side_ resource that enhances the HTML content of a page when it is on the client. It's scope of responsibility is the DOM once it gets to the client. This JavaScript should not be dynamically generated. All the information it needs should be in the DOM because if it's not then clients without JavaScript cannot get that information. You can also use ajax to query the server for additional information as an _alternative_ to submitting a form or redirection to an URL. As for the actual question, yes Razor should be able to do this.

Comment: Sure - Javascripts scope of responsibility is the DOM (and some light client notification as per support for alert, etc) . Take an ajax request for a partial view - you still need to get a value 'some how' to the URI to request. This is a clear and easy case for somewhere in the code to use @Model.CustomerId in forming the URL. I'm not advocating anything beyond that point and that distinct case is fairly standard and is not messy by any means. This comes quite in handy for jQuery.Load().Dialog() calls. You need to know 'some value' in order to properly enhance the html content on the page.

Comment: @AdamTuliper `@Model.CustomerId` should be used to form an URL in the HTML. The javascript is supposed to _unobtrusively_ upgrade that url from the html. You do not need to write the customer id into the javascript, it is already in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor doesnt like tags inside of a script block so its causing your parsing issue. If you really want the code there, then just ignore the warning.

for giggles, rename 'script' to textarea and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks fine. Could you confir if at runtime the page produces what you expect? The IntelliSense engine for Razor v1 still has some quirks, especially if you have C# inside of JavaScript inside of HTML.